# Firefox autocomplete for url is defaulting to an unpreferred url

Tags: firefox, slack

Sorry if this a dumb question or if the title is unclear but,

I work for a website,

`Https://www.website.com`

And we recently made a slack account at

`Https://www.website.slack.com`

When I type in `we` into the address bar

It used to autocomplete/autofill to `Https://www.website.com` but now it autocompletes to the slack page. This is actually very frustrating since I hit that domain a zillion times a day and very rarely intend to hit the slack domain. Is there anyway to have FF default autocomplete to the plain domain without having to purge the slack domain from my history?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `slack` entry from autocomplete by positioning to it in the
drop-down list and hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd>, then continue on using the
`website` URL.

Hopefully, when the time comes to use `slack` again, it will not be set as the
preferred one.